# Is there an elegant way to bridge two devices/streams in Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, iostream

Given two stream-oriented I/O objects in [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/), what is the simplest way to forward data from one device to the other in both directions? Could this be done with [boost::iostreams::combination](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) or [boost::iostreams:copy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) perhaps? Or is a manual approach better--waiting for data on each end and then writing it out to the other stream? In other words,how does one leverage [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/) to produce a minimal amount of code?

An example application would be streaming between a serial port and TCP socket as requested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484740/converting-serial-port-data-to-tcp-ip-in-a-linux-environment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With standard C++ streams you can do the following, can't you do something similar with Asio?

```
// Read all data from in and write to out.
void forward_data( std::istream& in, std::ostream& out )
{
  out << in.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Does that block until the input stream is closed? What about bidirectional streams?

Comment: out will be fed data until in end-of-file is reached, you will have to look into how Asio implements the buffer; if an end-of-file is sent when the input is closed or not. rdbuf() is a method of std::ios so it's available on both std::istream and std::ostream.