# Can I use a serial port as TCP/IP interface on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, tcp, redhat

### Background

We want to run an FTP server on a Red Hat Enterprise OS. The problem is, the machine we have does **not** have an Ethernet port/interface (please don't ask why; it's just a project requirement).

We only have a serial port.

### Question

Is there COTS / open source software that I can use to make serial port "look" like a an Ethernet port? My project is commercial. We run Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3.

**Note:**
Pardon me if my post title is unclear. If you can think of a better title, please suggest or simply change the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also be able to use PPP (point-to-point protocol) to another endpoint over a serial connection.

Comment: For an ftp server utilizing an ethernet connection? Not sure how this applies.

Comment: There is no real ethernet connection per the OP's post.  PPP will provide a pseudo-network interface that the server can use as an endpoint, presumably with a connection made from a machine at the other end of the serial link.

Comment: @Joe, thanks for the answer. Do you happen to have a tutorial link that explains how to configure PPP for serial?

Comment: I haven't had a need to use it in years.  There's an OLD HOWTO that still has relevant info here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html

Comment: With PPP, your serial port "looks like ethernet" only in the sense that it offers a network port.  There's no hardware ethernet connectivity.  You need to connect PPP to another PPP host; if that host has network connectivity it can route the packets for you.  This is how dial-up ISPs work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of things, but I'm not sure if it's the answer to my question. Please comment as you see fit:

- [ser2net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/)
- [Eltima Serial To Ethernet](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/)

I also found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484740/converting-serial-port-data-to-tcp-ip-in-a-linux-environment) asked on SO, but I'm not sure if it's related to what I'm trying to do:

Comment: Got a response from ser2net project admin, and it *cannot* be used for my scenario.

Comment: Got a response from Eltima, and that software would not solve the problem either.