# Python indifference to serial / Ethernet

Tags: python, tcp, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with a device that uses the same protocol whether you're talking to it over a TCP socket or a serial port.  Either way, it's an ASCII command-based interface, in which you type your command at a prompt, followed by a newline, you get a response with a newline, and then a new prompt.

```
> IDENTIFY
DEVICE_TYPE_RESPONSE
> TEST POWER
OK
>
```

The program can and should block until it gets the new prompt, but there needs to be a timeout so you don't wait forever in case of sudden device death.  That timeout should be seconds so as not to falsely flag on a network glitch, but shouldn't force me to wait seconds once I've gotten my prompt character.

I'd love some way to abstract the interface so as to not care about what the underlying communications layer is.  Just pass it either an open socket or an open serial port and let everything happen.  Is there some good way to do this?  Preferably capable of running under Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the protocol in Twisted which allows you to use TCP or the serial port as a transport without changing your protocol implementation. Twisted also allows you to set timeouts/delayed callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Python's serial package provides a lot of useful stuff including some [serial over TCP/IP bridges](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#tcp-ip-serial-bridge). If you want to talk to it using ASCII/Telnet then you probably want the to use the '--convert' option with the Simple Serial to Network (TCP/IP) redirector.

Also you might want to take a look at this other related question on [Converting serial port data to TCP/IP in a linux environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484740/converting-serial-port-data-to-tcp-ip-in-a-linux-environment)