# xml messaging over serial port

Tags: java, c, xml, serial-port

Is there any way to communicate with the serial port via xml messaging? I mean I want send/receive a structured packet from high level (java) which parsing by the Embedded device (C). Is there any way to do that?? If xml messaging is not possible any other alternative way to send structured packet over serial port.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, a bloated format over a very low speed link into a device with very little memory... Are you _sure_ you want to use XML?

Comment: no. not xml I just want to use structured communication where i can send data like packet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial port is just the transport you have available.  You can theoretically run just about any protocol over serial port that you could run over other communication means.  Theoretically you could even run [TCP/IP over bongo drums](http://slashdot.org/story/03/09/27/175242/tcpip-over-bongo-drums).

If the embedded device supports it, you can run TCP/IP over the serial port, and pass your XML structure over TCP/IP based protocols.

[Converting serial port data to TCP/IP in a linux environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484740/converting-serial-port-data-to-tcp-ip-in-a-linux-environment)

Even if the embedded device cannot run a protocol like TCP/IP, you can still transmit XML messages over the serial port and interpret them in your C program.

Comment: my embedded device is not support all standard c library it supports very few. Is it possible to port into any embedded platform??

Comment: If your embedded system is based on Linux, the above link may work.  If not, tell us more about your embedded system.  At a minimum, you can send the XML message using whatever protocols are already supported on the embedded device and decode writing custom C or using a C XML library.

Comment: My system have some driver and zigbee api, It can communicating over serial port, but I want to communicate with a structured way. it supports stdio.h,string.h,fcntl.h like this portable libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at SLIP and SLIPMUX to send packet oriented protocols (wich XML files basically are) over serial line.

More details in this question: [sending packets over serial comms java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467950/sending-packets-over-serial-comms-java/41823403#41823403)