# Remote Rpi and GSM Module (Sim800l) Connection

Tags: python-3.6, pyserial, gsm, raspberry-pi2

im currently working on a project that uses Rpi and a GSM Module (SIM800l).
As of today, im working on a Heavy processing and Heavy database querying on the PI, im wondering if you can remotely access the GSM Module that is setup on a PI from another PC using pyserial? If not pyserial, what python library i can use to accommodate my needs?

For visualization purposes this is my setup now:

python_script.py(using pyserial to communicate to GSM Module) that is running on a RaspberryPi.

What i want to accomplish is:
Run the python_script.py on a much stronger and faster machine and remotely access the GSM Module using the pyserial (or other plugin).

Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you want exactly? Will SIM800l be connected to RPi for setup or will it be connect to faster machine? What is it you mean by remotely access the GSM Module .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

***PC1 <---- Sock1 ---->  RPi <---- ttyS1 ----> SIM800l***

where,

1. PC1 is the remote PC (faster powerful ..).
2. Sock1 is the TCP socket connected to RPi. (nc comes to rescue)
3. "ttySxx" is a file which represents "Serial Port" device (SIM800L) on Linux (RPI).

Please refer to following "QA" for an excellent coverage of the same.

[Converting serial port data to TCP/IP in a Linux environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484740/converting-serial-port-data-to-tcp-ip-in-a-linux-environment)